# Solving Gaussian Process posterior analytically in PyMC3

Tags: pymc3

I'm used to doing a Gaussian Process regression in GPFlow which lets you do this to solve for the posterior analytically:

```
import gpflow as gp
from gpflow.kernels import RBF, White, Periodic, Linear
k = RBF(x.shape[1]) + White(x.shape[1])
m = gp.models.GPR(x, y, k)
self.model = m
m.compile()
opt = gp.train.ScipyOptimizer()
opt.minimize(m)
```

I've recently moved to PyMC3 and am trying to accomplish the same thing as above. I've found in the documentation this bit of code (https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/GP-slice-sampling.html#Examine-actual-posterior-distribution):

```
# Analytically compute posterior mean
L = np.linalg.cholesky(K_noise.eval())
alpha = np.linalg.solve(L.T, np.linalg.solve(L, f))
post_mean = np.dot(K_s.T.eval(), alpha)
```

Ultimately I want to be using the GP for a regression on unseen data. Is using `np.linalg` the right way to analytically solve a GP posterior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. As stated in the tutorial, they implemented Algorithm 2.1 from [Rasmussen's GPML](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/), and he explicitly uses left matrix divide notation (`\`), which indicates to use a linear solve.  For example, in theory (i.e., real number system),

```
A\b === A^(-1) * b === x
```

where `x` solves `A*x = b`.  But in a practical computational domain (e.g., IEEE floating point), this equivalence breaks down because `solve(A, b)` is faster and more numerically stable than `inv(A) * b`.

The left matrix divide (`\`) notation is commonplace in Numerical Linear Algebra, and I'd venture that the most salient explanation for its preference is that it tacitly reminds students to **never compute a matrix inverse**, unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So it /is/ supposed to use numpy's linear algebra package to solve it, as opposed to something that comes with `pymc3`?

Comment: Yeah. The other alternative, is to use one of the [methods from Theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/slinalg.html), but from the descriptions, they seem to rely on the SciPy libraries internally anyway.